# Adding content pages to local html directory on offline network

Tags: php, jquery, html, lan

In our office, we use a local server to host all of our files. I have created an html page for internal use where we can have how-to's, tutorials, and informational documents available to our employees. I've done this by creating a directory on our network `S:/folder/` where I have index.html as well as subfolders where I have put the content pages `S:/folder/subfolder/content.html`. So far everything works fine, I edit `index.html` to add links to new content pages. I would like to incorporate a way for my coworkers to more easily add additional content instead of giving me the content.html page they created, then me needing to add a link and specify the file location, etc. I am brand new to development and so far only have experience in html and css, with limited exposure to javascript/jquery. 
My list of page links looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="../folder/subfolder/content1.html" target="_blank">Content 1</a>
  <a href="../folder/subfolder/content2.html" target="_blank">Content 2</a>
</div>
```

When my coworker creates a new content page, he saves it into `S:/folder/subfolder` and I go to the above container and copy+paste a new entry and manually add the new link. I've considered two options to do this automatically:
Could I make an html `<form>` where he can input the file name and the link text and then use jQuery to add an entry to the list using these variables?

```
function addLink(url,subfolder,txt) {
  $(".container").append('<a href="../folder/' + subfolder + '/' + url + '" target="_blank">' + txt + '</a>');
}
```

It doesn't seem like this would work as it would only add the link temporarily? Is there a way to do this permanently?

If not, I read that php might be needed to handle this form data, but I'm not sure how that would work. Would I be able to run a php script on our offline network? Or would I have to setup a local web server with php and mySQL?

Like I said, I am new to all of this, so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Why not just use an existing CMS like Drupal or Wordpress? You need to use some kind of persistent storage to track things like the name of the link and the location of the file.  You could write the html to disk and keep the names in a json file or something like that.  Either way, you will need some PHP or other CGI to manage the persistent data.

Comment: Agree with the other commenter; you're re-inventing the wheel. IMO you should use a Wiki.